Firebase Flutter Facebook auth , the getter 'token' isn't defined for the type 'AccessToken'
enter image description here
Future<User?> signInWithFacebook() async {
    try {
      // Trigger the Facebook Authentication flow
      final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

      if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
        final accessToken = result.accessToken!;
        
        print('AccessToken type: ${accessToken.runtimeType}');
        print('AccessToken properties: ${accessToken.toString()}');
        
        // Create a credential using the token
        final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);

  
    return _auth.authStateChanges();
  }
}

no matter what i did. I couldn't resolve this issue
It just doesnt get the token. How can i resolve this man i am stuck here 2 hours. HOW HARD CAN IT BE

Have you enabled|configured the Facebook Sign-in Method for your Project on the "Authentication" tab of Firebase Console?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think your accessToken type is AccessToken? not an AccessToken, so it can find the token value.

Change this:
final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);

into this:
final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken!.tokenString);

The class AccessToken no longer has a property called token, instead now it's tokenString.
You can check here:
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_facebook_auth/latest/flutter_facebook_auth/AccessToken/tokenString.html

this solved it thanks

If the answer helped you please mark it as correct so other people would know that it works @yusufçelebi

you're welcome, glad it helped!
